# Is mail rejected by Exim's !verify = header_syntax ACL item, with RFC 2047-encoded From/To headers, legitimate?

Tags: email, spam, exim, access-control-list

A recent Exim upgrade added this to the default `acl_smtp_data` ACL:

```
.ifndef NO_CHECK_DATA_VERIFY_HEADER_SYNTAX
deny
  !acl = acl_local_deny_exceptions
  !verify = header_syntax
  message = header syntax
  log_message = header syntax ($acl_verify_message)
.endif
```

This causes some messages to be rejected. For instance, the following header from a spam message:

```
2020-03-02 09:22:48 1j8hHk-0000gS-3Y H=(static-181-143-69-27.une.net.co) [181.143.69.27] F=<Danika@une.net.co> rejected after DATA: header syntax (unqualified address not permitted: failing address in "From:" header is: =?utf-8?B?IkRhbmlrYSIgPERhbmlrYUB1bmUubmV0LmNvPg==?=): unqualified address not permitted: failing address in "From:" header is: =?utf-8?B?IkRhbmlrYSIgPERhbmlrYUB1bmUubmV0LmNvPg==?=
```

Decoding the offending header, we get:

```
00000000  22 58 69 6d 65 6e 61 22  20 3c 58 69 6d 65 6e 61  |"Ximena" <Ximena|
00000010  40 76 69 6c 2e 63 6f 6d  2e 75 61 3e              |@vil.com.ua>|
0000001c
```

Which looks like a perfectly fine value for a `From` header to me.

Do I risk rejecting legitimate mail by using `verify = header_syntax`, or are headers such as the one above invalid and safe to reject?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delving into RFC 2047:

```
5. Use of encoded-words in message headers

An 'encoded-word' may appear in a message header or body part header
   according to the following rules:

[...]

(3) As a replacement for a 'word' entity within a 'phrase', for example,
    one that precedes an address in a From, To, or Cc header.  The ABNF
    definition for 'phrase' from RFC 822 thus becomes:

    phrase = 1*( encoded-word / word )

    [...]

   These are the ONLY locations where an 'encoded-word' may appear.  In
   particular:

   + An 'encoded-word' MUST NOT appear in any portion of an 'addr-spec'.
```

It appears that an `encoded-word` can be used for the text preceding the address in a header, but not for an address itself. So it's safe to use `verify = header_syntax`, as long as we assume that legitimate mail will not contain headers that violate RFC 2047 by sneaking addresses into the encoded part of headers.

On the other hand... what about [RFC 6854](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6854)? This allows headers such as:

```
From: Automated System:;
```

to be fair, the RFC also says that this syntax "is only for Limited Use" ("appropriate for use only in limited or unique circumstances", e.g., experimentation, per [RFC 2026](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2026)). So I won't lose much sleep over it!

Answer (score 1):

RFC2047 has been misapplied

section 5 allows three different ways that encoded words can be used this conforms to none of them.

The most that an encoded word can cover is a "phrase" or an "atom"

```
  "Ximena" <Ximena@vil.com.ua>
  "phrase" <atom@atom.atom.atom>
```

Answer (score 0):

in Exim4

> 2022-12-20 12:08:55 [20316] 1p7g6p-0005Hg-7L ***************** RUNNING acl_custom_check_data ++++++++++++++
>
> 2022-12-20 12:08:55 [20316] 1p7g6p-0005Hg-7L H=(mx27.sXXXXXXXse.com) [XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX]:X I=[XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX]:25 F=steve@domain.com rejected after DATA: malformed address: steve@domain.com\n may not follow steve@domain.com : failing address in "To:" header is: steve@domain.com <steve@domain.com>

The email was being sent from a Python script.
The python script set the To header as "steve@domain.com <steve@domain.com>"

I traced this rejection to the problem of having an email address string at the beginning of the To header. When changing the Python script to use "steve <steve@domain.com>" the email was not rejected by Exim4's header verify.

[Based on the info from Sam Morris above](https://serverfault.com/a/1005260/65092) I am interpreting the "@" symbol in the To header "name" prefix, as being an "encoded" word, and that is the reason why the message was being rejected by Exim4.

The other possibility is the json object used in the Python script to pass the parameters to the smtp api, had a line break after the "name" : "steve@domain.com" in the source code, and that line break was passed to the api, and encoded in the smtp message headers, which triggered the rejection in exim4.

I hope this helps someone who is experiencing the same rejection error in exim4 rejectlog.